# How to add a close button to a newly opened window in ionic for an android device?

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have code like this:

```
$scope.viewOrderDetails = function viewOrderDetails(detail) {
    var newWin = open('orderdetails.html','windowName','height=300,width=300');
    newWin.document.write('html to write...');
    newWin.document.write(detail);
    //<input type="button" value="Close this window" onclick="self.close()">
}
```

I want to add close button to newWin. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

**UPDATED:**

```
newWin.document.write('<input type="button" value="Close this window" onclick="window.close()">');
```

it works in `ionic serve`, but when running in my pad device, when i click "Close this window", the window can not be closed.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in your question itself...you can try this...

```html
newWin.document.write('<input type="button" value="Close this window" onclick="window.close()">');
```

Comment: thanks, it works in ionic serve, but when running in my pad device, when i click "Close this window", the window can not be closed...